# NetworkManager Access point stops working after a few days

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, networkmanager

I have a raspberry pi configured as access point using network-manager.
After a few days (4-7 days), the access point stops working, i can still see it, but not connect to it.
It looks like the failure occurs when trying to authenticate the network, here is a log of network manager on the pc when trying to connect the pi's access point:

```
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.0948] device (wlp2s0): disconnecting for new activation request.
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.0949] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation') [100 110 60]
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.0950] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB whoopsie[1925]: [11:10:32] offline
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.1588] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="0437402f-74fe-4856-950b-d8940ec4ad47" name="NMTest6" pid=3060 uid=1000 result="success"
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.1627] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation') [110 30 60]
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB avahi-daemon[1139]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::136b:a3e4:2b0c:be88 on wlp2s0.
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB avahi-daemon[1139]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::136b:a3e4:2b0c:be88.
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB avahi-daemon[1139]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.2295] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5789
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.2296] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1688.719693] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 84:16:f9:4f:9b:58 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB wpa_supplicant[2216]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=84:16:f9:4f:9b:58 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB avahi-daemon[1139]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.117 on wlp2s0.
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB avahi-daemon[1139]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.117.
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.2435] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB avahi-daemon[1139]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB dnsmasq[2751]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.2664] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'NMTest6' (0437402f-74fe-4856-950b-d8940ec4ad47)
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB dbus[1047]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB dbus[1047]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp2s0]: new request (2 scripts)
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <warn>  [1615194632.3155] sup-iface[0x2588ee0,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3162] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3218] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3220] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3258] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3267] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'NMTest6' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3271] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3392] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3936] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3940] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'NMTest6' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3941] Config: added 'ssid' value 'NMTest6'
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3941] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3941] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3942] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3942] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194632.3977] sup-iface[0x2588ee0,wlp2s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Mar  8 11:10:32 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB gnome-session[1886]: (captive-login:6526): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_allocation: assertion '_gtk_widget_get_visible (widget) || _gtk_widget_is_toplevel (widget)' failed
Mar  8 11:10:33 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194633.4090] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar  8 11:10:34 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB wpa_supplicant[2216]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (SSID='NMTest6' freq=2412 MHz)
Mar  8 11:10:34 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1690.896678] wlp2s0: authenticate with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19
Mar  8 11:10:34 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1690.898951] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 1/3)
Mar  8 11:10:34 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194634.4212] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar  8 11:10:34 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1691.004566] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 2/3)
Mar  8 11:10:34 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1691.113840] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 3/3)
Mar  8 11:10:34 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1691.216573] wlp2s0: authentication with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 timed out
Mar  8 11:10:34 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194634.7561] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar  8 11:10:34 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194634.8569] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar  8 11:10:36 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB wpa_supplicant[2216]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (SSID='NMTest6' freq=2412 MHz)
Mar  8 11:10:36 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1692.750811] wlp2s0: authenticate with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19
Mar  8 11:10:36 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1692.753039] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 1/3)
Mar  8 11:10:36 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194636.2700] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar  8 11:10:36 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1692.860576] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 2/3)
Mar  8 11:10:36 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1692.965612] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 3/3)
Mar  8 11:10:36 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1693.068541] wlp2s0: authentication with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 timed out
Mar  8 11:10:36 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194636.6209] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar  8 11:10:37 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194637.1212] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar  8 11:10:37 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB whoopsie[1925]: [11:10:37] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar  8 11:10:37 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB whoopsie[1925]: [11:10:37] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar  8 11:10:40 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB wpa_supplicant[2216]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (SSID='NMTest6' freq=2412 MHz)
Mar  8 11:10:40 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1697.086840] wlp2s0: authenticate with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19
Mar  8 11:10:40 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1697.089241] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 1/3)
Mar  8 11:10:40 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194640.6098] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar  8 11:10:40 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1697.196558] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 2/3)
Mar  8 11:10:40 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1697.304353] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 3/3)
Mar  8 11:10:40 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1697.408682] wlp2s0: authentication with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 timed out
Mar  8 11:10:40 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194640.9604] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar  8 11:10:41 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194641.9625] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar  8 11:10:43 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB wpa_supplicant[2216]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (SSID='NMTest6' freq=2412 MHz)
Mar  8 11:10:43 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1699.513578] wlp2s0: authenticate with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19
Mar  8 11:10:43 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1699.516094] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 1/3)
Mar  8 11:10:43 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB NetworkManager[1156]: <info>  [1615194643.0361] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar  8 11:10:43 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1699.620588] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 2/3)
Mar  8 11:10:43 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1699.730717] wlp2s0: send auth to b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 (try 3/3)
Mar  8 11:10:43 Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB kernel: [ 1699.840520] wlp2s0: authentication with b8:27:eb:b7:3e:19 timed out
```

This problem repeated on a few different raspberry pis (version 3b+) with the same raspbian lite version.

Tried to disable ipv6, and power save (`iw dev wlan0 set power_save off`), both didn't change anything.

Taking the connection down and then up again makes the access point work again.

This doesn't happen always, i have set 6 different pis and the problem happened only in 3 of them until now.

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Comment: Any reason you are using network manager rather than hostapd?  Have a look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-bridged.md and https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md - I had one running for a good month / six weeks as a temp solution this way with no issues.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, i tested it and it's working, now i'll try to see if it's stable :) Thanks for the tip!